# SurfaceView not clearing old Photo

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have this SurfaceView and when I drag a bar the zoomController increases, and when I drag it the other way the zoomController decreases.

The effect is to enlarge and shrink the photo, the problem I am having is that the old photo stays so if I make it really big and then small the large image stays in back of the small image.  Why is this happeneing?

public SView(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
            zoomController = 100;
            x = 100;
            y = 100;

```
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        while(isItOk)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            Paint p = new Paint();

            tattoo = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);
            if(tattoo != null)
            {
                tattoo.setBounds(getWidth() / 2 - zoomController - x, getHeight() / 2 - zoomController - y, getWidth()/ 2 + zoomController - x, getHeight()/ 2 + zoomController - y);
                tattoo.draw(c);
            }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as you said, the `SurfaceView` is not clearing the old image. This is intentional. If you want to clear it, you need to do it manually. Try this before you (re)draw your image:

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Yeah, but this covers the XML File in the back...  Is there a way to just clear the SurfaceView?

Comment: Try `Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);` maybe